# Promise.race continuing to run after one promise rejected

Tags: javascript, promise, cancellation

Isn't promise.race supposed to terminate all promises when one of them have rejected/resolved?

```js
var cancelDeferred = new cancellation()

Promise.race([cancelDeferred.promise, new Promise( (res, req) => {
 setTimeout(() =>{
  console.log("hey")
 }, 2000)

})]).catch(e =>{
 console.log(e)
})

setTimeout(() => {cancelDeferred.cancel()}, 500);


function cancellation () {
    const token = {};
  
    token.promise = new Promise((_, reject) => {
      token.cancel = () => reject(new Error('cancelled'));
    });
  
    return token;
  }
```

In this code, one promise is cancelled after 500ms, so that should result in .catch to console log right?

No, it still logs "hey", why is this?

Comment: No, a promise cannot be "terminated". And it doesn't know how that it should `clearTimeout`.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal behaviour. It is not because a Promise rejects, that a `setTimeout` will be cancelled. `Promise.race` provides you with a promise that rejects as soon as any of the given promises rejects (or fulfils if all of them fulfil). It does *not interrupt* any asynchronous code that might still be pending. After the `Promise.race`-returned promise settles, it will become ignorant of any *settlement* of any of the other promises that were passed to it, but will not prevent asynchronous code execution.

`setTimeout` has its own "contract" that can only be broken if you call `clearTimeout`. No promise rejection can prevent a `setTimeout` callback to be called.

To make it work, you need a call to `clearTimeout`:

```js
var cancelDeferred = cancellation()
var clearDeferred = delay(2000);

Promise.race([cancelDeferred.promise, clearDeferred.promise]).catch(e =>{
    console.log("catch", e.message)
    clearDeferred.clear();
})

setTimeout(() => {cancelDeferred.cancel()}, 500);


function cancellation () {
    const token = {};
  
    token.promise = new Promise((_, reject) => {
        token.cancel = () => reject(new Error('cancelled'));
    });
    return token;
}

function delay(ms) {
    const token = {};

    token.promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(); // promise makes sense only if there is this call
            console.log("hey");
        }, ms);
        token.clear = () => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            console.log("timer cleared");
        }
    });
    return token;
}
```

Comment: if call `clearDeferred.clear()`, won't `token.promise` be an always pending promise? which will cause memory leak.

Comment: @crazyones110, if the timer is cleared, then the callback that was given to `setTimeout` can be garbage collected. So then also a reference to the promise's `resolve` function is removed, which in turn can allow for the garbage collection of the promise object itself (if it has no other references). I don't see a reason for some memory leak.