# How i can get rerurn by Timeout? Or how abort function run with Timeout

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise, timeout, settimeout

I need to abort or return from a function before it completes on its own.
I have tried this, but it returns 100

```
async function Later() {
    setTimeout(() => { return 10 }, 1_000)
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2_000))
    return 100
}

console.log(await Later())
```

Also tried with throw:

```
async function Later() {
    try {
        setTimeout(() => { throw 10 }, 1_000)
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2_000))
        return 100
    } catch (error) {
        return error.message
    }
}

console.log(await Later())
```

But try doesn't work with setTimout

P.S. Instead of promis, my code has an api call. I need a solution where I don't have to wait for the function to complete to prevent a hang at that point

P.P.S.

Tried race, but it not aborting second function:

```
async function Later() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 100))
        console.log(i)
    }
    return 'Later'
}

const data = await Promise.race([
    new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res('First promise'), 100)),
    Later()
])
console.log(data)
```

Logs after it:

```
First promise
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I've came up with this idea, is it good or not?

```
const GetTransaction = (hash) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => reject(new Error(hash)), 3_000)
        let data
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1_000))
                data = await getBlockWeb3.eth.getTransaction(hash)
                if (data) {
                    clearTimeout(timeout)
                    resolve(data)
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`${new Date().toLocaleString()} :: Error fetching transaction:`, error.message)
                await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
            }
        }
        clearTimeout(timeout)
        resolve(null)
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement request timeout? If yes, see: [Using Promise.race() to implement request timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race#using_promise.race_to_implement_request_timeout)

Comment: See also [Stop other promises when Promise.all() rejects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48762751/5459839) and [Promise.race continuing to run after one promise rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57017668/5459839)

Comment: `getBlockWeb3.eth.getTransaction` should take an [`AbortSignal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal) that you trigger after a given time, using [`timeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/timeout_static)